# Cannot approve/reject items in a List View web part on modern site

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, custom-list

I have a "modern" team site in SharePoint Online.  I have a list in the site that has Content Approval enabled.

When I put a List View web part on the home page of the site, the only options I have on the Actions (3 dots) menu are Share, Copy link, and Delete.

In order to Approve or Reject, I have to go into the "full" list to get those actions. Is there any way to get those available in the list view web part on the page?

This is the list view web part:
[image]

This is the list, same view, but from the "full" list (through Site Contents):
[image]

Comment: Please post a screenshot if possible

Comment: I added screen shots.

Comment: @managgia Are you checking the list and list view webpart on page with same user? If yes, try to create a site page and check the same over there.

Comment: Yep. Both me, and I am a site owner, site collection admin and O365 Admin.

Comment: @managgia Did you try to create a site page and check the same over there?